# If logic to write one of three texts into a cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I would like to write text a, b or c in E3 depending on the result.

The code crashes Excel.

```
Sub calculate()
Range("B2").Activate
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    If ActiveCell.Value + ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) + ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = 3 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Text A"
    ElseIf ActiveCell.Value + ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) + ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = 2 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Text B"
    ElseIf ActiveCell.Value + ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) + ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) < 2 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Text C"
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you intend to move down the column or just examine **B3** over and over again ??

Comment: I've edited the code. I would like to write text a, b or c in E3 depending on the result

Comment: Looks to me like your Do While .. Loop should just be an If .. Endif block. Unless the ActiveCell value is changed inside the loop it will never exit.

Comment: **1.** Find the last row as shown [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) **2.** Use a `FOR` loop to loop through the cells in that column. If you use a `Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""` then the code will stop mid way if there is a blank cell in between. **3.** Use a `Select Case` instead of `If-EndIf`. It is much easier to read and maintain. **NOTE** These are just my suggestions and not a hard and fast rule to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some variables! Maybe something like this:

```
Sub calculate()
    Dim c As Range, v
    Set c = ActiveSheet.Range("B2") 

    Do While c.Value <> ""
        v = c.Value + c.Offset(0, 1).Value + c.Offset(0, 2).Value
        If v = 3 Then
            c.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Text A"
        ElseIf v = 2 Then
            c.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Text B"
        ElseIf v < 2 Then
            c.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Text C"
        End If
        Set c = c.offset(1, 0)
    Loop

End Sub
```